groupby and Multiplying a column by scalar
I wrote this code:
tmp_ml['mode_dur_secs_lb'] = tmp_ml.groupby(['id', 'c_num']).apply(
    lambda x: x['mode_duration_secs']*0.9)

table:



id
c_num
mode_duration_secs




a1
116
20


a1
279
3


a2
9
19


a3
16
16


a3
17
19



TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

can u provide us df so we can take look. Probably this problem came from dismatched index.

What are you trying to achieve here? As far as I understand, how does the groupby affect multiplying the mode_duration_secs column? Did you mean to aggregate the sum/mean of mode_duration_secs and then multiply it by 0.9?

It is not clear why you are using groupby because there are no groups of ['id', 'c_num'] in your data.  And there seems to be no intention to aggregate data if there were any groups. What do you want to see as a result?

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what you need help with, as others have said. Please read [ask] and make a [mre] including desired output. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Assuming your function is a dummy function, you have to pass group_keys=False to groupby to avoid having the grouping columns set as index:
tmp_ml['mode_dur_secs_lb'] = (tmp_ml.groupby(['id', 'c_num'], group_keys=False)
                                    .apply(lambda x: x['mode_duration_secs']*0.9,
                                           include_groups=False)
                             )

If this is your actual function, then groupby is useless, just go with:
tmp_ml['mode_dur_secs_lb'] = tmp_ml['mode_duration_secs']*0.9

Output:
   id  c_num  mode_duration_secs  mode_dur_secs_lb
0  a1    116                  20              18.0
1  a1    279                   3               2.7
2  a2      9                  19              17.1
3  a3     16                  16              14.4
4  a3     17                  19              17.1

explanation
(tmp_ml.groupby(['id', 'c_num'])
       .apply(lambda x: x['mode_duration_secs']*0.9)
)

#########  <- you don't want those levels
id  c_num   
a1  116    0    18.0
    279    1     2.7
a2  9      2    17.1
a3  16     3    14.4
    17     4    17.1
Name: mode_duration_secs, dtype: float64

(tmp_ml.groupby(['id', 'c_num'], group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x['mode_duration_secs']*0.9,
              include_groups=False)
)

# now they're gone
0    18.0
1     2.7
2    17.1
3    14.4
4    17.1
Name: mode_duration_secs, dtype: float64

